# input form number with 3 decimals bug html

Tags: html, input, decimal

I want to enter numbers in an input form and display the entered number when user press Enter.

```
<input type="number"  onKeyPress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { myFunction(this); }"></input>
<p id="demo"></p>

function myFunction(that) {
       document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = that.value;
   }
```

Everything works correctly except when I enter a number with exactly 3 decimals (E.g. 0.123). The bug occurs only with a number that has 3 decimals. It's absolutely non-sense.

Here is a link for a jsfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/ckfnd445/2/

Comment: What kind of bug is it? I've just checked and see nothing strange

Comment: Yes, the fiddle worked for me too.

Comment: when I enter 1.123 it displays 1123. It removes the dot character. But it's not the case if I enter 1.1 or 1.12 or 1.1234 etc. I am using firefox

Comment: It works correctly with chrome! It's really weird

Comment: I confirm that there is a bug only with firefox (v. 41.0.2).

Comment: I guess it happens because FF is trying to interpret '.' and ',' as a separator between thousands. You can try 1.123.456 and see the same behaviour. And yes, it shows nothing if fails to interpret that way

Comment: @SerhiyChupryk Thanks! And do you know if there is a way to change that?

Comment: It's working for me with Firefox 41.0.2...

Comment: @krlzlx Maybe it depends on the local browser language options. I am in Switzerland. It is really an annoying bug...

Comment: I'm also in Switzerland

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What I discovered and that may help you. If your localization is not en-us you may have an issue :)

So to fix your input control problem try to specify at least `lang` attribute for the control, like this:

```
<input type="number" lang="en" onKeyPress="if (event.keyCode == 13) { myFunction(this); }"></input>
```

Also you may want to specify `step="any"` to let your browser validate the control correctly (because default step is 1). Or you may want to disable validation for it

Comment: Thanks! Yes actually I am in Switzerland.  lang="en" solved my problem

Comment: Good to know if I encounter this behaviour.